# Power Plan [Shutting Down]

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 the problem is when I am using pc with plug in for  charging or without charging from starting time it working normally.But when I plug out the pc from charger when the pc is running it shows that "Your pc is Critical Battery Situation". After few second showing this message the pc is shut down automatically. I try for change the power plan from setting,there is no option either shut down.There is a Hibernate option but I am unable to select that,it is hidden and I am unable to select that.

Answer (score 1):

When your computer is plugged in, it gets its power from the mains. It uses this power to run the computer and to try to charge the battery. When you unplug it, the computer tries to get its operating power from the battery. The immediate `Critical Battery Situation` message means that, after all the time running on battery (seconds in this case), it has noticed that the battery is running out of charge.

*This means that your laptop battery is failing, and needs to be replaced.*